# YQL - wrong query

Tags: csv, yql

can someone tell me whats is wrong with this yql statement:

```
select symbol, Earnings_per_Share, Dividend_Yield, week_Low, Week_High, Last_Trade_Date, open, low, high, volume, Last_Trade 
from csv
where url="http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=YHOO,GOOG&f=seyjkd1oghvl1&e=.csv"
  and columns="symbol,Earnings_per_Share,Dividend_Yield,Last_Trade_Date,week_Low,Week_High,open,low,high,volume,Last_Trade" 
    in(select * 
       from yahoo.finance.historicaldata 
       where symbol = "YHOO" 
         and startDate = "2009-09-11" 
         and endDate = "2010-03-10")
```

i want to get this properties:
http://www.electronics4design.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/priceTable.jpg

Answer (score 0):

what are you trying to get ?
If all you need is to get **YHOO** data, just try this

```
select symbol, Earnings_per_Share, Dividend_Yield, week_Low, Week_High, Last_Trade_Date, open, low, high, volume, Last_Trade from csv where url="http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=YHOO&f=seyjkd1oghvl1&e=.csv" and columns="symbol,Earnings_per_Share,Dividend_Yield,Last_Trade_Date,week_Low,Week_High,open,low,high,volume,Last_Trade"
```

I just removed the **GOOG** from the ***url=...***

Comment: The query is Ok, but when i put it in the script i get many rows. i need to get only one row of YHOO. here is the script: